# Invalid column name when inserting - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity framework using code first. I have 3 tables in database:

- Place
- Profil
- PlaceMember

It's a many to many relation. A place can have many Profils as members and a profil can be a member to many Places. The PlaceMember is the relational table.
Code of PlaceDTO:

```
[Table("Place")]
public partial class PlaceDTO
{
    public PlaceDTO()
    {
        Members = new HashSet<ProfilDTO>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string description { get; set; }

    public DateTime dateOut { get; set; }

    public DateTime createDate { get; set; }

    public int? canceled { get; set; }

    public int profilId { get; set; }

    public int addressId { get; set; }

    public virtual AddressDTO Address { get; set; }

    public virtual ProfilDTO Profil { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProfilDTO> Members { get; set; }
}
```

Code of Profil class:

```
public partial class ProfilDTO
{
    public ProfilDTO()
    {
        Devices = new HashSet<DeviceDTO>();
        Notifications = new HashSet<NotificationDTO>();
        Places = new HashSet<PlaceDTO>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string pseudo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string firstname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string lastname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15)]
    public string phone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string emailAdresse { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string password { get; set; }

    public DateTime lastUpdatePassword { get; set; }

    public DateTime lastUpdateProfil { get; set; }

    public DateTime createDate { get; set; }

    public byte[] picture { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<PlaceDTO> Places { get; set; }
}
```

Code of PlaceMember class:

```
 [Table("PlaceMember")]
public partial class PlaceMemberDTO
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int placeId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int invitedId { get; set; }
}
```

In database, the **placeId** and **invitedId** are both identity key of the table.
When I'm trying to add a new place to the Place table, I'm getting that PlaceDTO_id is not a valid column name despite the fact that the place table in database has an column named id and is the identity column.

```
 context.Address.Attach(place.Address);
 context.Address.Add(place.Address);

 place.addressId = place.Address.id;
 context.Places.Attach(place);
 context.Places.Add(place);            
 context.SaveChanges();
```

The place object, put in param, contains 3 members that exists in Profil table.
When I remove the **Members** field from the **PlaceDTO** table, the place is inserted but nothing added to the **PlaceMember** table.

What's wrong ?

Comment: I don't see where your junction table is even coming into play. Do you have some fluent code that configures the relationship, MapLeftKey, MapRightKey, ToTable("PlaceMember"), etc? http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: You not need table PlaceMember at all. EF will generate it automatically. But if you still want to create it manually, you should create `ICollection<PlaceMemberDTO> PlaceMembers` at both classes and create references to this tables(as foreign keys - composite primary key) inside table `PlaceMember`.